# Is there anyway to see data in google analytics that is not there?

Tags: google-analytics

I just started at a company and the new web host hasn't been sharing data to google analytics so there is no info at all for the past 6 months in my analytics account. They just put in the tracking code last friday. Is there anyway to see data in google that is not there??

Comment: Not likely. If there was no tracking code, Google has not been collecting any data.

Answer (score 2):

No, of course not. You cannot see something that isn't there. And you couldn't even recreate the data even if you had it from other sources, since Google does not allow to import historical data.

However you might have alternatives - your webserver should keep a logfile, and you can analyze this with programs like [Awstats](http://www.awstats.org/) or [similar (free or commercial) software packages](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=log%20file%20analyzer). This is really old school (log file analysis was the way to go before cloud based javascript trackers became common) and the results will not quite match data collected via Google Analytics, but it should give you at least a broad idea what was going on on your site.